# Solving $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {x-5}}=-\frac 16$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I got stuck on below equation $$\frac{1}{\sqrt x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {x-5}}=-\frac 16$$ I tried to power both sides, use substitution and ... like these
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt {x-5}}=u \to x= \frac{5u^2+1}{u^2}\\\frac{u}{\sqrt{5u^2+1}}-u=-\frac16\\ \frac{u^2}{5u^2+1}=u^2+\frac 1{36}-\frac 13 u$$ then I tried to multiplying by $$\sqrt{x(x-5)}$$ to both sdies but bcome a 4th degree equation. then I tried grphical calculator  for $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {x-5}}-\frac 16$$ and see the solution is $x=9$
I take $f'(X)$ and see $f'>0 $ and $f(x)$ is increasing function, so must have one root.    but I want to know  if there is a tricky way or simple Idea to solve the equation without dealing with 4th degree equation ?
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @AnneBauval : Thank you, but I tried graphical solving.  I want to solve it by an ordinary method.

Comment: If $-\frac{1}{6}$ is replaced with another rational number in the equation, the solution is generally an algebraic number with degree 4.  Hence, it seems unlikely that the equation can be solved without either guessing or using the rational root theorem to solve a quartic equation.

Comment: Not sure how you could do better than guessing $x=9$ and then proving this is the only solution with the derivative of $f$.

Comment: As hinted by @L.F., instead of guessing, the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) leads you to the solution $u=1/2$ for your 4th degree equation.

Comment: Shouldn't your last $-\frac16$ (in the definition of $f$) be $+\frac16$?

Answer (score 1):

Let us take it from here:

$$\frac{u^2}{5u^2+1}=u^2+\frac 1{36}-\frac 13 u\implies\frac{5u^2}{5u^2+1}=\frac{12u-1}{36}\implies$$

$$180u^4-60u^3+5u^2-12u+1=0$$

That's not a nice equation...but also not that terrible since we knew we were going to get something like that (see comment of L.F. below your question).

We can hope...just hope... that there's  rational solution $\;\frac rs\;$ ,and since the equation is one in integer numbers, by the rational root theorem we know that it must be that $\;r\mid 1\,,\,\,\,s\mid 180\;$.

Since there clearly cannot be a negative root, it must be

$$r=1\;,\;\;s\in\{1,2,3,4,6,8,10,12,15,20,24,30,60,90,180 \}$$

It can be annoying but there is only a finite number of tries, and we're happy to find out that the first rational non-integer possibility is a hit: $\;\frac rs=\frac12\;$ , so

$$\frac12=u=\frac1{\sqrt{x-5}}\implies x-5=4\implies x=9$$

Comment: $180u^4-60u^3+5u^2-12u+1=(2u-1)P(u)$ where $P(u)=90u^3+15u^2+10u-1$ [has a positive root](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+90u%5E3%2B15u%5E2%2B10u-1+for+u%3D0.08+to+0.09) $u\approx0.084$. I can't understand why we don't see the corresponding value for $x$ as a root on the [plot of $f(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {x-5}}+\frac 16$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+1%2Fsqrt+x-1%2Fsqrt%28x-5%29+%2B1%2F6+for+x%3D140+to+150).

Comment: @AnneBauval I plotted the polynomial equation on Desmos and there appears to be a root in $\;0.0841\;$ ... and it doesn't appear as a solution of the original equation because, as written in my answer, it *must be*  $\;x>5\;$ , otherwise the equation is complex non-real.

Comment: @AnneBauval Since the equation was solved by squaring, we know sometimes some non-solutions get into it. This is one of those cases since, as the OP wrote correctly, the function is monotone ascending so it only can have one single real solution

Comment: Thank you! I should have remembered that, or even (re-)found it!

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}=-\frac{1}{6}$. Now after this step we can write that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}-\frac{1}{6}$. Now let's square both sides. Therefore, $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x-5}-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{x-5}}+\frac{1}{36}$. Now this implies that $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x-5}=\frac{1}{36}-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{x-5}}$. Therefore $\frac{-5}{x(x-5)}=\frac{\sqrt{x-5}-12}{36\sqrt{x-5}}$. Therefore, $\frac{-180}{x\sqrt{x-5}}=\sqrt{x-5}-12$. Now, let $\sqrt{x-5}=u$. Therefore $x=u^{2}+5$. Therefore, $-180=(u^{2}(u^{2}+5))-12u(u^{2}+5)$. Therefore, $-180=u^{4}+5u^{2}-12u^{3}-60u$. Therefore, $u^{4}+5u^{2}-12u^{3}-60u+180=0$. Now by "Trial and Error" method, we get $u=2$. Now, $\sqrt{x-5}=u$. Therefore, $x=9$.

Comment: I cancelled $(x-5)$ and $\sqrt{x-5}$ because $x\neq5$. If $x=5$, then the above equation will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible trick**:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{\sqrt x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}=-\frac{1}{6} & \iff \frac{\sqrt{x-5}-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x \sqrt{x-5}}=-\frac{1}{6}\\
& \\
& \iff \frac{\sqrt{x-5}-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x \sqrt{x-5}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x-5}+\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x-5}+\sqrt x}=-\frac{1}{6}\\
& \\
& \iff \frac{x-5-x}{\sqrt x \sqrt{x-5}(\sqrt{x-5}+\sqrt x)}=-\frac{1}{6}\\
& \\
& \iff \sqrt x \sqrt{x-5}(\sqrt{x-5}+\sqrt x) = 30
\end{aligned}
$$
**Substitution** $\quad u=\sqrt x,\, v=\sqrt{x-5} \quad$ give us this equation:
$$
uv(u+v)=30 \implies \text{one possible solution, i.e.} \quad u=3, v=2 \implies \boxed{x=9}.
$$